# PHP - array_diff all similar values are compared and removed

Tags: php, arrays

I would appreciate a little help . I have tried `array_diff()`, intersect combos but not able to get my expected return.

Here is an example what i want to do.

First array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 21
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
)
```

Second array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 21
    [1] => 2
)
```

using `array_diff(firstarray, secondarray)` i get following.

```
Array
(
    [2] => 1
)
```

But what i want

```
Array
(
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
)
```

keys from firstarray and secondarray wont necessarily be same.

Comment: You have to write your own function to do this

Comment: Why would you want the 2 also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little snippet should help you achieve what you want. Here we'll loop the second array, and remove the first occurrence of each value it finds from the first array.

```
$first = array(0 => 21, 1 => 2, 2 => 1, 3 => 2);
$second = array(0 => 21, 1 => 2);

foreach ($second as $v) {
    unset($first[array_search($v, $first)]);
}
```

Output from `$first` after looping:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
)
```

If you wish to keep the `$first` array intact, copy it into an other variable, and loop that, i.e. `$new = $first;` and unset from `$new` instead of `$first`.

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/tiIXp)

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_true_diff($arrayOne, $arrayTwo = []) {
    if (count($arrayOne) < count($arrayTwo)) {
        $tmp = $arrayOne;
        $arrayOne = $arrayTwo;
        $arrayTwo = $tmp;
    }

    $diffs = [];
    foreach ($arrayOne as $key => $value) {
         if (!isset($arrayTwo[$key]) || $arrayTwo[$key] !== $value)  {
            $diffs[$key] = $value;
         }
     }
    return $diffs;
}
```

`print_r(array_true_diff(firstarray, secondarray))`

Above function could fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

in that case you can use "in_array" to check if exists and "array_search" to get the key and "unset" to delete an element from the array like this:

```
    $array1 = array(21, 2, 1, 2);
    $array2 = array(21, 2);
    $result = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < count($array1) ; $i++) { 
        if (in_array($array1[$i], $array2)) {
            unset($array2[array_search($array1[$i], $array2)]);
        } else {
            array_push($result,$array1[$i]);
        }
    }
```

and the output will be:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below function:

```
function arrayDiff( $a, $b ) {

    $a = array_count_values($a);
    $b = array_count_values($b);

    $out = array();

    foreach( $a as $key => $value ) {

        if( isset( $b[ $key ] ) ) {
            $value -= $b[ $key ];
        }

        $out = array_merge( $out, array_fill( 0, $value, $key ) );
    }

    return $out;
}

print_r( arrayDiff( $a, $b ) );
```